# 18V from printer USB port. Is that normal?

Tags: voltage, usb

I have HP 1514 printer. I noticed that the usb type A plug coming from printer has as buzzing feeling when touching skin. I connected one multimeter probe to the USB plug and the other one to ground pin in my power outlet as shown in the sketch below. The multimeter shows 18V. Shows 0 when measuring current with same setup.

[image: Test Setup]

I believe that this is not okay? What could be the cause? Could I damage my Macbook by using this printer (I have used it for a year with no problems, though)

Comment: My printer is not grounded, so the USB "GND" often has a potential against earth. Has your USBs "GND" continuity to earth (or should it have?)

Comment: I'd expect a higher voltage actually :P

Comment: "Shows 0 when measuring current with same setup" you shouldn't be measuring current the same way you measure voltage, a meter set to current will have ideally no resistance thus you would be shorting power and ground

Comment: AC or DC? If AC you are seeing the Y-capacitor current leakage.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'm still in the process of learning about electronics, so please forgive if my questions don't make much sense.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm not exactly sure what is continuity, but if it is the thing on multimeter that beeps when completing circuit between probes, then no. Multimeter shows 0l

Comment: @Gorloth What would be the correct way how to measure current in this case then?

Comment: @winny DC has 18V, when measuring in AC mode, it has in fact 28V!

Comment: Well, your multimeter could be crap for measuring DC while trying to reject AC but do you have a very long lead and high current draw though it to explain the extra 13 V DC? A 12 VAC voltage drop to your local ground from local neutral is easy to jusify or motivate but DC is a different matter. Name and brand of multimeter? A circuit diagram or sketch of what you measure?

Comment: @winny Multimeter is UNI-T UT33D, rough sketch - https://s22.postimg.org/gyhc5jhz5/IMG_0243.jpg

Comment: @GerbyfromDerby there's no correct way to measure current in this case. Luckily for you, there was no fault, so you didn't blow anything up or hurt yourself.

Comment: Good stuff. What if you measure to minus/USB GND in the USB socket to ground? Do you get 18 V there as well?

Comment: "I connected one multimeter probe to the USB plug and the other one to ground pin in my power outlet" Are you connecting the multimeter probe to the metal frame of the USB plug? Or, which pin on the USB plug are you connecting the multimeter probe to?

Comment: @hobbs I actually thought that I was measuring voltage wrong, since it is supposed to be measured parallely to the component (?(. And vice versa for current - that it has to be in direct line.

Comment: @winny Yes, same voltage there

Comment: @Kevin Fegan I get 18 volts from all 4 pins and frame as well

Comment: Contrary to comments above, it is possible to put an inline meter (self contained shunt) on a type A port to measure voltage *and* current under (suggested resistive dummy) load.
Chassis bashers should have one or two for testing the accessory's draw, not the host.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is normal, almost.

Your printer has a power supply, which is supposed to be "isolated" from mains AC. It does this by converting AC to DC, then converting the high-voltage DC into high-frequency AC, then it uses a transformer to reduce the voltage, and then rectifies it back to DC, to the level of digital logic and motor controls. The transformer preforms the isolation, but not a full isolation, because there is still some parasitic capacitive coupling, mostly between primary and secondary winding. It is this parasitic coupling that creates some discomfort when you make a contact between **ungrounded** printer and **grounded** computer or AC outlet ground. If you would try to use a high-impedance oscilloscope probe, you will likely see some ugly waveform at mains frequency (50 or 60 Hz or 100 or 120), with amplitude up to 55V (on a 110V AC). This "leakage" exists on all AC-DC adapters, to one degree or another.

However, this parasitic current is usually small, about 100uA, but on a bad PSU it can be up to 500uA, in accord with UL safety standard. When you connect a USB cable, this current will be shorted by system shield, and will do no harm.

Comment: That only explains the AC part, not where 13 V ofDC comes from.

Comment: @winny, not 13V, but 18V :-). And I am not sure if it was really any DC. Or the particular AC-DC PSU has some coupling asymmetry, due to some inexpensive half-way secondary rectifier, or else.

Comment: Not impossible, but even the tiniest of auxiliary power supplies I've taken apart have all been full bridge.

Comment: @winny -- the power supply's ground is 18v above the wall socket ground, that's all. (It could be that the power supplies ground is too high, or the wall socket's ground is too low). -- Either way, it shouldn't be a huge deal, since the wall socket ground is not the ground that the USB is using for logic. -- Voltage is just the "potential" difference between two points, it's relative, not absolute.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83, Again, that's for AC. There is no DC voltage at all on the grid side or the transformer would saturate immediately. Something needs to drop or inject DC voltage before you can measure it.

Comment: @winny many switch mode supplies have an class Y capacitor over the output transformer, *typically connected to the negative side of the bridge rectifier*. If this is leaky or the board is corroded (like 100meg resistance), it could give a DC bias to the measurement, example circuit in a simulator: https://tinyurl.com/yh7o9uqh

Comment: @Ferrybig Interesting! If you remove the series resistance on the input, does it persist?