# Does iphone shock transfer AC or DC current to body?

Tags: ac, dc, safety, iphone

Suppose an iphone gave a little jolt when pressing the power button. Is that AC or DC current? The phone was connected to a laptop which was connected to a power outlet.

Comment: Could it have been static electricity? If so, that consists of a short current spike. More information can be found in documents [like this](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND410-D.PDF) which describe the Human Body Model.

Comment: DC of course, there is no AC in play.

Comment: @dandavis But it was connected to power outlet through the laptop, so won't that bring in AC current?

Comment: no, the connection to the laptop is DC, via the big warm block somewhere between the wall plug and barrel jack.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks a lot. Last question, is this current similar to [this one](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/news/10180428/iPhone-electric-shock-reportedly-kills-Chinese-bride-to-be.html)? If so, the current in the link is DC too?

Comment: If she was using a mystery charger in a place as effectively poorly regulated as China, she could've got hit with the full brunt of the mains.

Comment: @Henry: no, that's a failed USB charger, not a laptop. a lot of chargers are shodily made and AC made it to the DC side, either from low clearance on the PCB or a poorly wound transformer. there's no way the laptop wouldn't get fried if the human got AC from it. so i guess that means it safer to charge from your laptop in china, as you'll have an indicator something bad is happening with the power...

Comment: Post the schematic.

Comment: This is a legit question. The answer is that correctly functioning switch modes contain capacitors (X capacitor) that leak a small current from the mains to the user to ground. This can be felt, but is safe. See my answer or many others on ese on this topic 
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/364697/ground-loop-isolation-of-a-usb-powered-device/364775#364775

Comment: @HenryCrun So is the current AC or DC?